# get random char in a specific range in java

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

Am designing wumpus hunting program using java. Where i can include three gold, 3 pits, one wumpus, one player. and the position of the game item should be random generator.How to generate random characters in 2d array .
How to specify the range for the characters in java.
Thanks.

Comment: The best way to do it is to go and write some code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Show me your efforts !

Comment: This is my code so far.. i want exactly 1 wumpus, 1 player, 3 gold, 3 pit, others are clear ground in the 4*4 grid

Comment: Edit your original question. We need to see you trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `random.nextInt()` to generate a random number for the position. 
If you want to generate a random character you should use :
`(char)(random.nextInt(max-min)+min)`. Where the max and min value are the ascii code of the max and the min char.
If you only want to generate a char in some char you should create an array with these character and use `yourArray[random.nextInt(yourArray.length-1)+1];`

> Edit : You have to create the object random at the beginning of your
>   code. Random random = new Random();